# PhantomJS does not see dropdown options populated by AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, html-select

I've been trying to scrape a site using a PhantomJS/Selenium setup in Python.

There's a dropdown in the page that, when selected, populates the options of another dropdown. When I'm automating this with Firefox, when I select_by_visible_text on the first dropdown, the second one gets populated.

However, the same code doesn't work with PhantomJS.

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PHANTOMJS_PATH)
## browser = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, WAIT_TIME)
browser.get(URL)

Select(browser.find_element_by_id('DropDown0')).select_by_visible_text('XXX')

def condition_wait_for_dropdown(driver):
    ret = False
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="DropDown1"]/option'):
        ret = True
    return ret

wait.until(condition_wait_for_dropdown)
```

I have tried using a hard-coded sleep instead of the custom waiting condition, and checked the DOM - the second dropdown never gets populated at all.

Can this be a problem with the webpage itself? If so, how do I work around this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this works with Selenium+Firefox, so the possibility exists that this is a bug in the PJS driver itself.

Comment: You've covered the bases. I'd start using `execute_script` to check what is going on in the JavaScript VM.

Comment: There's an onchange event. When I try: browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("DropDown0").dispatchEvent("onchange")'); I get an exception saying:
{u'message': u'UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events Exception 0'}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) takes an `Event` object, no?

Comment: Ah - I don't know JavaScript, as is perhaps obvious. I found this page: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11289 , and changed my code to:    browser.execute_script('var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent"); evt.initCustomEvent("change", false, false, null); document.getElementById("DropDown0").dispatchEvent(evt);') .  This ran without error but didn't actually populate the second dropdown.

Comment: Solved my problem, thks. Your code works fine in my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this, so best to leave it here for posterity.

I had an input field in the page form, so after selecting the first dropdown I moved the focus to the input field, and sent an ENTER to it. The second dropdown got loaded immediately.

Still don't know wth is wrong with this web page.